# Ошибка со шрифтом, только в Mozila Firefox

Tags: шрифты, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело. Во всех браузерах отображается всё нормально без ошибки, в FireFox же шрифт не применяется, и в отладчике ошибки:

> downloadable font: cmap: unexpected
> range shift (3 != 4) (font-family:
> "AGHelveticaCyr" style:normal
> weight:normal stretch:normal src
> index:0) source:
> file:///C:/Users/SkyWay/Desktop/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-ver1%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/fonts/AGHelveticaCyr.ttf
> style.css
>
> downloadable font: cmap: failed to
> parse table (font-family:
> "AGHelveticaCyr" style:normal
> weight:normal stretch:normal src
> index:0) source:
> file:///C:/Users/SkyWay/Desktop/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-ver1%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/fonts/AGHelveticaCyr.ttf
> style.css
>
> ```
> downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family:
> ```
>
> "AGHelveticaCyr" style:normal
> weight:normal stretch:normal src
> index:0)
>     source: file:///C:/Users/SkyWay/Desktop/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-ver1%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/fonts/AGHelveticaCyr.ttf

Вот мой код загрузки и использования шрифта: http://jsfiddle.net/dudkj7sf/

Comment: Эти новые единицы измерения пока неодинаково поддерживаются всеми браузерами, а некоторыми (IE) поддерживаются лишь частично. Лучше использовать скрипты или медиазапросы  http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Странно, версию у меня 32 Firefox. Да и два других шрифта, загруженных таким же образом, никаких ошибок не выдают.